# Invalid coercion: () as xs:string+ while performing search:search($qtext)

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am sending an http get request to the MarkLogic server, something like -  http://localhost:7040/index.xqy. Request is captured using `xdmp:get-request-field("q")` which accept the query into a variable, say $qtext and pass it on to `search:search($qtext)`.
This returns a 404 not found error stating
`<error:xquery-version>1.0-ml</error:xquery-version> <error:message>Invalid coercion</error:message> <error:format-string>XDMP-AS: (err:XPTY0004) $qtext as xs:string+ -- Invalid coercion: () as xs:string+</error:format-string>`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Basically $qtext is empty sequence () which is not allowed in search:search. What I did is -
`let $query := if(fn:empty($q-text)) then "" else $q-text`.
you can also change the request to something like `localhost:7040/index.xqy?q=`
This link helped http://jaketrent.com/post/unexpected-results-marklogic-xquery-type-coercion/

As suggested, this is better `xdmp:get-request-field("q", "")`

Comment: xdmp:get-request-field() also takes an optional second parameter, which is the default value for the field. You could do `xdmp:get-request-field("q", "")`.

Answer (score 2):

A very useful idiom for providing default values concisely in XQuery relies on the conversion rules of xs:string to xs:boolean along with the behaviour of

```
$sequence[.]
```

Using '.' as the predicate in a sequence expression evaluates each item in the sequence as a boolean, if true then that item is included, if false it is excluded. The conversion rule for xs:string to boolean is 'true' for non-zero length strings and 'false' for zero length or empty sequences. The following is the verbose equivalent for a sequence of xs:string.

for $item in $sequence 
   return 
     if( not( empty( $item) ) and string-length($item) > 0 ) 
     then $item else ()

Thus the following pattern is often used to say "Use $x IF $x is not empty or zero lenght, otherwise use $y.

```
( $x , $y )[.][1]
```

Note the '[1]' which selects the first item that resulting from the prior expression.
An example to provide a default value for $x like

```
 ($x , "Default value")[.][1]
```

The same for results or arguments to functions:

```
cts:search( doc() , ( get-the-search-string() , "default")[.][1] )
```

where 'get-the-search-string()' might return an empty sequence or a zero length string or a sequence of 1 or more strings.

In your example you want an empty string as the default so a slight variant can be used to allow a "" but not a ()

```
let $query := ($q-text,"")[1]
```

Comment: definitely concise.  And it appears accurate.  But any concerns about readability/maintainability?